# How to install a drain cover in the shower for this opening in the floor?

Tags: shower, drain

We have a tiled shower in the house we just bought.  The drain cover is not there anymore.

[image: shower drain hole and cover]
[image: shower drain cover test fit]

I bought the drain cover that is closest in size.  However, it does not fit perfectly. There is about 1/8" gap all around.

There are two rusted screws I believe on either side of the hole.

At first, I made a ring of plumber's putty and put it on top of the hole...and slightly in the hole.  I then sat the drain cover on it and pressed down.  I then realized that it is quite soft.

What is the best way to install the drain cover for my shower?

Answer (score 1):

You bought a tub drain cover, not a shower one.  I would just use silicone in a few places to secure it.  Do not wrap the silicone all the way around as it may hinder water from going down.

Comment: Do you mean put some in the drain and then push the cover on top of the silicone?

Comment: Yes or easier put silicone on the bottom and place it.  It will secure it and also allow you to remove with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

The drain cover you got is designed to fasten with a screw in the center. This is mainly for commercial applications. You could perhaps make it work by screwing a plastic inverted U-shaped strip on the underside to provide some slight friction on the sides of the drain, but this might be ill advised as it could come off and plug the drain!

The one in my tub has projections down into the drain to keep it from sliding off. The drain cover stays in by gravity and friction. You want to be be able to easily remove it for cleaning.

You could get a round drain screen that projects down into the opening. They come in various sizes and just lay the one you got on top for better appearance.
Here's one that looks OK but may not come in right size, but this is the idea.

[drain strainer Bed Bath and Beyond](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/rsvp-endurance-reg-sink-strainer/1045966996?skuId=45966996&ioid=HH000032&mcid=PS_googlepla_nonbrand_kitchenaccessories_&adpos=1o2&creative=43742642389&device=c&matchtype=&network=g&product_id=45966996&gclid=Cj0KEQiAk5zEBRD9lfno2dek0tsBEiQAWVKyuAVxKrcGLgr6a0g6Pe_PZVtvIQsc7NPR2MgoZX4b8LQaAt3P8P8HAQ)

Google Danco mesh strainer combo pack 88886. One of the three would fit.
[Danco mesh strainer combo pack 88886](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E0Z85Y)

The one in our tub is almost exactly like this from Lowes https://www.lowes.com/pd/Danco-2-in-Chrome-Stainless-Steel-Kitchen-Sink-Strainer-Basket/3428334